# Alternative Tyre Allocation: what happens if it rains?

Tags: formula-1

The 2023 Hungarian Grand Prix will be using the new Alternative Tyre Allocation rule for Qualifying.

What happens if it rains during Qualifying? All I have heard is they must use hards for q1, mediums for q2 and soft for q3.

Comment: Could you provide a source for where you heard this?

Comment: they are using the "alternative tire allocation " this weekend. It was supposed to be used at Imola ,but that was cancelled.Formula 1 to answer your ?

Comment: Hi @keva454 - I have edited your question to make it clearer to the question I think you're asking - If you feel that my changes are incorrect - feel free to [edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/29022/edit) the question again

Answer (score 1):

If the session is declared "wet" by the race stewards, then the teams will have a free tyre choice.

From [Mercedes' explainer](https://www.mercedesamgf1.com/news/five-things-you-need-to-know-alternative-tyre-allocation) on the new rules:

> **Drivers have four sets of the intermediate tyre, and three sets of wets, to use per weekend. If a session is declared wet, they then have a free tyre choice.** This could be from those inters or wets, but also across the slick tyre range if track conditions permit. That means we may not see the mandated compound running in qualifying.